# Add multiple conditions inside single-line loop in python

Tags: python, list, loops, python-itertools

I am using `beautifulsoup` to scrape a website, get all the `p` elements with class `text`. Sometimes inside this `p`, there exists an element with class `emoji` that  I want to save. So i originally made this loop:

```
for p in soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'text'}):
    emoji = p.select('emoji')
    ems = ""
    if emoji:
        for em in emoji:
            ems += (str(em['alt']))
    result.append([p.getText(), ems])
```

I transformed this into a single-line loop:

```
result = [[x.getText(), y['alt']] for x in soup.find_all("p", {"class": "text"}) for y in x.select('emoji')]
```

The problem with my single-line loop is:

- It saves `p` where exists class `emoji` **only**. I need to save all `p` and when `emoji` doesn't exist i want to save an empty string like **['lorem ipsun' , '']**. Where should i add this condition in single-line loop?
- If multiple `emoji`s exist, it saves the same `text` **n** times, **n** being number of emojis, each time with a different **single** emoji. How can i save all the emojis seperated by a comma instead? Tried to do `''.join(','+y['alt'])` instead of `y['alt']` but didn't change my result.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Less lines is not always better. That list comprehension is almost not readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import functools

result = [ [p.getText(), functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [ str(em['alt']) for em in p.select('emoji')])] for p in soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'text'})]
```

Comment: It threw an error, what was missing is **the initial value for reduce()**. So eventually this line worked: `result = [[p.getText(), functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [str(em['alt']) for em in p.select('emoji')], '') ] for p in soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'text'})]
`

Answer (score 0):

Took @AniketNavlur's answer and modified it a bit, eventually this worked:

`result = [[p.getText(), functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [str(em['alt']) for em in p.select('emoji')], '') ] for p in soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'text'})]`

Answer (score 0):

The way to write a for loop in a single line, mostly used in Data Science Project, You can use this way, as we have six labeled fake news LIAR:

```
Labels:  ['barely-true' 'false' 'half-true' 'mostly-true' 'pants-fire' 'true']
```

to represent this as a binary labels:

We use the following way:

```
labels = [ 1 if lab=='false' or lab=='pants-fire' or lab=='barely_true'  else 0 for lab in df.is_fake]
```

Hope to help many of you, who want to do the same way in many problem-solving.